# Images in Reports

Tags: civireport

Is it possible to get a report with a list of names and their profile image? I have looked at some of the report templates, but I can't find where you can choose an image.

Comment: if your cms is drupal then it is easy to do this via a Drupal View. i can add this as an answer if interested in more instructions

Comment: Yes I am using Drupal, can I get a printable report using views?  If you have any instructions that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you can get both print and PDF, try https://www.drupal.org/project/views_pdf or https://www.drupal.org/project/print. i think we mostly use the latter which provides both

Comment: Please do add instructions, Pete, this is exactly the problem I am having, and creating a custom report template seems far too drastic a solution.

Comment: sent a view for testing on your system